# Compare two rows with conditional formatting but "offset" result

Tags: excel, compare, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to compare and highlight all the rows that have the same value (Column G) after each other.
My current formula is `=$G2=$G3` for the conditional formatting, see green color.

This is my result:

[image]

My issue:

I would like to offset the highlight **result**, so that always the "second result" is marked. So if G4=G5, then I want G5 to be highlighted. Now I only get G4 is marked.

Is it possible to offset the result by one row or some other suggestion?
I've tried to use `=IF($G2=$G3;OFFSET(G2;1;0))`.
I also used a dummy column (Column I) to offset the result and base the conditional formatting upon, but would be neat to have it in the formula.

[image]

---

Table

```
| Index | Account     | Date       | TransType | SymbolName | Qty | Price | Fee   |       |
|-------|-------------|------------|-----------|------------|-----|-------|-------|-------|
| 119   | Portfolio A | 2015-03-30 | DIV       | AA         | 66  | 0,05  | 0,99  | FALSE |
| 120   | Portfolio A | 2015-04-28 | DIV       | BAC        | 42  | 0,23  | 2,898 | FALSE |
| 121   | Portfolio A | 2015-05-15 | Buy       | MSFT       | 42  | 16,58 | 12,95 | TRUE  |
| 123   | Portfolio B | 2015-05-15 | Buy       | MSFT       | 42  | 16,58 | 12,95 | FALSE |
| 122   | Portfolio B | 2015-05-15 | Deposit   | * Cash     | 1   | 732   |       | FALSE |
| 131   | Portfolio A | 2015-08-03 | DIV       | APPL       | 42  | 0,18  | 2,26  | TRUE  |
| 132   | Portfolio B | 2015-08-03 | DIV       | APPL       | 42  | 0,18  | 2,26  | FALSE |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may try in this was as shown in the image below,

• Select the whole range, i.e from `A2:H8` as shown in the above post

• From `Home Tab` --> Click `Conditional Formatting` Under `Styles Group`

• Click `New`,

• `New Formatting Rule` Dialog Box Opens,

• Select the Rule --> `Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format`

• Place the below formula, in the edit rule description

```
=($D2=$D1)*($G2=$G1)=1
```

• Click `Format` --> Choose preferred `Font` or `Fill` Color From `Font` or `Fill Tab`

• Press `OK` --> `OK`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Thanks for helping me to think in the right path.
I could simplify my problem to this: `=($G2=$G1)` and then apply only to range `A2:H8`. Important is to start the apply range to one row less than you compare.

Comment: @Wizhi Yes I was thinking the same, however I thought If you are considering the Transaction Type as well, hence shown that way! Glad it worked for you, Thank you very much!